# Why do XHTML tags work in HTML5 documents and vice versa?

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype, web-frontend, html4

According to [this document](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp) there are some `XHTML` tags, that are not supported in new `HTML5` standard, for example [big](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_big.asp) and [strike](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strike.asp). However when I declare my html document as `HTML5` they still work for some reason, consider this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html /> <!-- HTML5 decalration -->
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- These tags should not work, because the document is declared as HTML5, but they still work -->
        <big>Hello</big>
        <strike>123</strike>
    </body>
</html>
```

Same applies vice versa, there many other `HTML5` tags that are not supported in `XHTML` standard, for example [svg](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_svg.asp) tag, however when I declare my document as `XHTML` they still work. Consider this example:

```
<!-- XHTML declaration -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">  
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Should not work because SVG are not supported in XHTML standard -->
        <svg width="100" height="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

The browser I used is the current version of `Google Chrome`.
Can anyone explain why this is happening? What is the point of declaring the document as `HTML5` or `XHTML` if the browsers will support both regardless of `DOCTYPE` specified?

Comment: With what mime type are your serving the XHTML page? `application/xhtml+xml` or `text/html`?

Comment: @connexo neither, I just opened the html file on my PC locally. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Of course it does. You need a webserver that sets the correct mime-type, the `!DOCTYPE` is not relevant for that.

Comment: HTML and XHTML are the same language. Which elements work in one, work in the other, barring the odd edge case. The only differences are the syntax, and case-sensitivity. There is no point whatsoever in stating which you are using in the DOCTYPE. If you are opening the file locally, it will be treated as XHTML if it has an ".xhtml" extension and HTML otherwise.

Comment: @Alohci What's the point of `DOCTYPE` tag then, if the browsers will interpret it the way they want anyway?

Comment: In a document treated as HTML syntax, it switches between standard mode, almost standard mode and quirks mode.  In a document treated as XHTML, it does nothing at all, and can be omitted. It's mostly just a remnant of an earlier time, when it indicated the rules that a *validator* should use to determine if the markup was valid. Modern validators do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example:

These are so-called **deprecated** tags that you *can* still use in HTML5, but they're not recommended. They could be removed any time by browsers (although this is pretty unlucky).

The second example:

Most browsers like Google Chrome or Firefox don't render XHTML as XHTML. They actually render it in HTML5. The things that are different in XHTML are converted to HTML5 using a preprocessor. Because SVG isn't part of XHTML standard, it won't be converted but just stays as it is, and thus displayed like in HTML5.